# iframe not showing on frontend when using a CMB2 field

Tags: plugins, metabox, iframe

I have a custom field manually coded using CMB2: https://cmb2.io/.
Here is the code:

```
$cmb_pages_customtext->add_field( array(
        'name'  => esc_html__( 'Content', 'defaulttheme' ),
        'id'    => $prefix . 'customtext_content',
        'type'  => 'wysiwyg',
        'sanitization_cb' => false,
    ));
```

I want to be able to add an iframe to the custom field. When I add the iframe code to the field, it saves it in the page edit screen but the iframe doesn't display when viewing the actual page. Is there something I need to add to get the iframe to display on the actual page?

Comment: I don't know why I got downvoted. My question was for a specific problem in WordPress.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I actually figured out the problem. It was a wp_kses_post function that was the cause. The wp_kses_post function was stripping the iframe tag. Obviously I removed the wp_kses_post function.

Comment: this is a very weak answer. ok, so that was the problem, how did you fix it?

Comment: It's a sufficient answer. I didn't think I needed to spell out the obvious solution of removing the  wp_kses_post function. I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

how do you assign the variable? use something like this?

```
$variable = esc_html( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'example', true) );
```

if yes, try removing [esc_html()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_html)